# ul after li or ul within li or both cases

Tags: html, css, standards

Can't we add 'ul' after 'li' like below? Eclipse showing some warning kind of message. But dreamweaver not showing the error or warning. Which is correct?

```
<ul>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
    <ul>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
</ul
```

Comment: Yes you can add it as long as they are enclosed within the UL in proper formating , Not an issue. In your case <li> tag should end after </ul> tag or else formatting is improper.

Comment: Is there any standards available- shouldn't write like this?

Comment: When you are nesting <ul> in another <ul> then it should come in between <li> tag , semantics of html programming.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the following way

```
<ul>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content</li>
<li>Content
    <ul>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This i know. i am asking about should we write both ways or not?